# What rules could a composer (e.g., Wagner) not follow and we would notice?

Tags: theory

I'm an experienced talented professional musician. So this sounds like I'm a child but I'm not. An off the wall question to be sure. What rules of 19th century theory would Wagner have hypothetically ignored, and we, the discriminating, would object to the dropping of whatever rules! E.g. did Wagner prepare dissonance and resolve, more often than not? Parallelisms!  How closely did he adhere to perfect intervals and parallels ? etc etc

Comment: I've voted to close this question, because the topic is too complex. However, it's an interesting, appropriate, and valuable question. Please consider writing in a more focused way. Perhaps focusing on a particular segment of music and/or a specific 19th century "rule".

Comment: There are no rules.

Comment: Welcome! Please read about [the topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), as well as [how to avoid subjective answers](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). There's a lot to say about the ways Wagner strained prior tradition, but the rules you mention might be more foundational in earlier periods. (Isn't the point of the [Tristan chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tristan_chord) how it "doesn't resolve"?) It might be useful to focus on a specific piece in a question.

Answer (score 4):

Two "rules" immediately come to mind that composers in the later nineteenth century (like Wagner) began to "break":

### "Illegal" Six-Four Chords

In the common-practice style, there are four types of acceptable six-four (second-inversion) chords. Because the fourth was a dissonance, chords with this fourth in the bass (like second-inversion triads) had to be treated with special care. These six-four chords were only acceptable if the bass of the six-four chord was either a) passing between two pitches a third apart, b) a pedal tone connecting two of the same pitch, or c) arpeggiating a given harmony. (The fourth type of six-four, the "cadential" six-four, is a subset of the pedal six-four.)

But in the nineteenth century, composers began relaxing these rules. Even as early as Mendelssohn we encounter six-four chords whose bass pitches are approached and left by leap in nontraditional ways, which would otherwise be unheard of in the Classical style.

### Resolving Chordal Sevenths

Chordal sevenths are dissonances, and as such they must be resolved properly: down by step. But a bit before Wagner we begin to see composers treated these resolutions very loosely, and by the time we get to the late nineteenth century we encounter plenty of composers that no longer choose to resolve (let alone prepare) their chordal sevenths accurately. These days, these resolutions are hit and miss; you can still hear their correct resolutions in something like jazz, but in something like blues the sevenths are often left hanging without a "proper" classical resolution.

### On "Objection"

But just because these rules were "broken" doesn't necessarily mean that discerning listeners objected to these rules. Rather, the loosening of these rules simply signaled a new musical style, and for that we should be thankful: without that new musical style we wouldn't have so much of the music we have today.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't really rules of the 19th century that your are asking about. The "rules" you mention like preparing dissonance and parallel part writing are 17th and 18th century practices. The origin of those rules in the old contrapuntal style of composition for the Church. As music moved into the secular realm, composers gradual adhered less and less to those old conventions. By the early to mid 19th century you can find examples from composers like Berlioz and Chopin which make clear composers were exploring musical possibilities that did not depend on the old Church style. They could explore other styles unapologetically. You might say that rather than there being "rules of the 19th century" the period was about "discarding the rulebook."

> ...we, the discriminating, would object...

As far as objections go you might be interested to read about the opposing schools of composers like [Schumann and Brahms versus Liszt and Wagner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_the_Romantics). Schumann and Brahms were the conservatives and Liszt and Wagner were the "new school" progressives. There was no one large body of listeners the new school departed from in terms of style. And it certainly wasn't a matter of "the discriminating", as in "discriminating taste", where the difference between the two schools could be explained as a matter of good and bad taste. Sure, the rhetoric the two sides used was full of condemnation, but a retrospective view sees it all as partisan politics, two sides jockeying for superiority. The reality is the two sides had different musical aims, different aesthetics, and they used different compositional methods to achieve those aims.

So, what I'm trying to get at is the objection to Wagner wasn't *really* about deviating from old 17th and 18th century conventions, it was a partisan opposition to a new school of music on the rise.

If you want to get into actual musical devices and the opposing schools, probably the most important thing to look at is *formalism* versus *program music.* It wasn't part writing issues like dissonance treatment or parallelism, all of the composers involve were perfectly capable of following part writing conventions, the issue was much deeper and fundamental: is music experienced in absolute terms through the *internal* relationship of elements, like the *recapitulation* of a subject, or by evoking reactions *external* to the music by sounds that convey scenes, actions, or moods? It's similar to representational versus abstract/non-representation work in the visual arts. Conservative 19th century composers and critics objected to non-formal musical depictions external to the music.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing a comment from @Todd Wilcox earlier, there really are no rules.  It's important to recognize that everything we have learned in music theory is *descriptive,* not *prescriptive*.  It exists to explain what was done in the past, not what "should be done" now.  It has quite a bit of value, of course.  With theory we can explain how common-practice music functioned, what things were expected by an audience, and what things might have been surprises.  But there has always been a large gap between theory that describes what has been done, and composers who write in the here and now.

That said, western tonal music has made a gradual shift from largely consonant [triad-based, mostly major and minor] textures with strictly controlled dissonances in the Renaissance, to chordal sevenths and diminshed chords in the Baroque, towards more and more dissonant music through the Classical and Romantic periods and into the 20th century.  All the time some composers have written conservatively within the bounds of what is expected and others have pushed into uncharted territory.

Comment: It looked like it double-posted.